# C# set opened workbook

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I started creating an Excel-Add-IN with C#.

what I need to do is simple, I need to set a workbook to a variable, the workbook is already running, I tried this but did not work

```
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook as Excel.Workbook;
        wb.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\ro_sg\\Desktop\\Pasta1.xlsx");
        Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets["Plan1"]; 
        Excel.Range range = ws.Range["A1"];
        range.Value = "Success";

        wb.Save();
```

The wb variable cannot find the workbook (gets null), and I can't see why.

Please, if any of you spot the mistake let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is it may not be finding the active Excel application upstream from when you set your workbook variable. It appears that your code is trying to create a new excel application (without a workbook) rather than get the existing one that is open.

Give this a try:

```
        Excel.Application excel = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)excel.ActiveWorkbook;
        wb.SaveAs("D:\\WeeeDueceDuece.xlsx");
```

Comment: That makes sense but wb is still getting null

Comment: Bizarre. Just to verify, when you run this you: Have a valid workbook open on your desktop?

Comment: Check one more thing actually. Since your previous code was firing up new empty application instances of excel: Go into task manager and see if you have any lingering excel process hanging out there. If so kill them all off and try again with the code I provided. Just to make sure you have a clean slate.

Comment: Thanks!
There was a lot of excel process hanging on task manager, when I killed then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to get a specific Sheet but if you try this: 
Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1]; 
It will get the first Sheet of your Workbook

Answer (score 0):

If your actual code doesn't have more in-between steps, it will always fail.  I'm surprised this line didn't error:

```
Excel.Workbook wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook as Excel.Workbook;
```

It's because a new instance of Excel does not necessarily create a new workbook.  You can check this with the following lines:

```
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks workbooks = application.Workbooks;
Console.WriteLine(workbooks.Count); // "0"
```

The new workbook, however, should create the default number of worksheets (usually 3, but editable).